# How to use this all-crashes-catching code to only take care of a single type of crash

Tags: android

In my app a crash logging service (splunk mint) is crashing big time.
I am setting a `UncaughtExceptionHandler` (because I have no power over the crash logging library) so that I can catch these crashes and prevent the app crashing because of the crash-logging library.

But I only want to catch these particular crashes with the `UncaughtExceptionHandler` and not all the crashes in the app.

I have this code, can you tell me how can I let the app crash if any exception that doesnt contain the words `splunk.mit` is caught?

```
public class MyApplication extends Application
{
  public void onCreate ()
  {
    // Setup handler for uncaught exceptions.
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler (new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler()
    {
      @Override
      public void uncaughtException (Thread thread, Throwable e) {
        // todo check if stacktrace contains `splunk.mint`
        // todo let all other crashes crash the app

        handleUncaughtException (thread, e);
      }
    });
  }

  public void handleUncaughtException (Thread thread, Throwable e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); 
    // todo deal with the crash somehow
  }
}
```

PS: Will this do the trick?

```
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler (new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException (Thread thread, Throwable e){
            if (!Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()).contains("splunk.mint")) {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    });
```

Actually I tried to test it but Android Studio wont compile because I havent caught the `throw e` line. What do I do?

PS2: I worked around Android Studio's limitation by substituting `throw e` with `throw new RuntimeException(e);` but is this the right way to go about my main question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
                if(e instanceof SplunkException){
                    //handle exception
                    System.out.println(e.toString());
                }else{
                    try {
                        throw e;
                    } catch (Throwable e1) {

                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        });
```